ROS MoveIt on RPI4 running on Raspberry Pi OS(64-bit)
I'm currently working on a 6 dof robotic arm controlled by ROS from RPI4. The Raspberry Pi4 runs Raspberry Pi OS(64-bit). My question is can I make MoveIt work on my RPI4 without that gui simulation?

You can use MoveIt programmatically using the MoveIt MoveGroup Interface.
MoveIt MoveGroup Python Interface
